# Sort unique lines based on one field, and decide which lines to output based on another

Tags: text-processing, sort

This is more about finding an elegant solution to a problem, I think I have a working solution.  I have the following input file format, tab-separated, on an Ubuntu machine:

```
AC003665.1  17  47813266    AGCAGGCGCA  83
RIOK3   18  23453502    GCAAGGCCCC  52
UBE2Z   17  48910880    CTAAGGATCC  48
CSNK1D  17  82251379    AATTTAGCCA  68
CSNK1D  17  82251379    AATTTCTTGT  38
SMURF1  7   99143726    GACAGATTGG  74
SMURF1  7   99143726    GACAGATTGG  61
RIOK3   18  23453502    GCAAGACTTT  69
```

I want to get only one line per occurence of field 3, the one that has the highest value in field 5. Output should therefore be :

```
AC003665.1  17  47813266    AGCAGGCGCA  83
CSNK1D  17  82251379    AATTTAGCCA  68
UBE2Z   17  48910880    CTAAGGATCC  48
SMURF1  7   99143726    GACAGATTGG  74
RIOK3   18  23453502    GCAAGACTTT  69
```

Order is irrelevant for my purposes. I have found a solution that involves sorting first on field 5, and then on field 3, that I think works:

```
sort -k 5,5nr input | sort -u -k 3,3n > output
```

It works with all my test files and I think should work in any case, as this should ensure that for every value of field 3 the sorting will see first (and therefore keep) the line with the highest value for field 5.

I however feel that there should be a more elegant (and maybe more foolproof) solution to that problem ? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your solution is probably best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data to be output is small enough to fit in memory then

```
awk '
    biggest[$3] < $5 { biggest[$3]=$5 ; saved[$3]=$0 }
    END { for (i in saved) { print saved[i] }}'
```

This will be faster in general, each line needs to be looked at once when it is deciding if it needs to be stored. The memory requirement is for the data that is outputted, so very repetitious input could be enormous.

This is in contrast with the sorting solution that needs multiple comparisons per line.  The sort based solution will be slower but will handle outputs that are too big to fit in memory.

Comment: That works great Icarus, thanks a lot ! The input file is expected to be of variable length, but should never reach a huge size, so memory is not an issue here.

Answer (score 1):

I would just sort by the 2nd and 3rd fields directly and pass through `awk` to keep the max value:

```
$ sort -k 3,3nr -k 5,5rn input | awk '!a[$3]++' 
SMURF1  7   99143726    GACAGATTGG  74
CSNK1D  17  82251379    AATTTAGCCA  68
UBE2Z   17  48910880    CTAAGGATCC  48
AC003665.1  17  47813266    AGCAGGCGCA  83
RIOK3   18  23453502    GCAAGACTTT  69
```

This has the advantage of only sorting the file once and also doesn't need to keep the whole file in memory. However, I would expect [Icarus's awk approach](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/533168/22222) to be faster since it only needs to read the file once.

Comment: That works too, and I think you could just sort by the 5th field only then, as then any first occurrence of field 3 is sure to be the one with the highest value in field 5.

ie `$ sort -k 5,5rn input | awk '!a[$3]++' ` 

should do the trick.

Thank you for the suggestion !